# How do I dynamically add image on hover to a button?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to add a on hover show image on a button that I am creating dynamically. I would love any suggestions.

```js
arrayHere = [{
  "date": "2/22/19",
  "note1": "Hello"
}, {
  "date": "1/11/18",
  "note1": "hi"
}]

populateData(arrayHere);

populateData(array) {
  var notesDates = document.getElementById("notes-dates");
  for (var i = 0; i < arrayHere.length; i++) {
    let dateLink = document.createElement("button");
    let displayNote1 = arrayHere[i].note1;
    dateLink.innerHTML = arrayHere[i].date;
    notesDates.appendChild(dateLink);

    dateLink.onclick = function() {
      DisplayChange(displayNotes1);
    }
  }

  function DisplayChange(displayNotes1) {
    document.getElementById("changeHere").innerHTML = displayNotes1;
  }
}
```

I've tried using JQuery, instead of getting errors, nothing shows up on the page.

Comment: use onmouseover in dateLink just like onclick.

Comment: Please include a [mcve] to your question.  The relevant HTML is missing

Comment: `dateLink.addEventListener('onmouseover', function() { // add image element });` and `dateLink.addEventListener('onmouseout', function() { // remove image element});` If the image is static, I'd prefer to use CSS and just apply the CSS Class to the button element to handle the hover effect. Is this what you're aiming for?

Comment: @daddygames, yes thank you! So could I add the image using appendchild or do you recommend another way?

Comment: @daddygames what should go inside the function??

Comment: @jenna it depends on what options you have available and how you want to implement. If you have static images, I recommend adding a CSS class `$(this).addClass('myImageCSS');` Are your image URLs dynamic or are you pointing to static images?

Answer (score 0):

CSS

```
.buttonWithImage {
    background-image: url("https://image.shutterstock.com/z/stock-vector-vector-illustration-of-goggle-with-two-eye-on-yellow-color-background-317985974.jpg");
    background-size: cover;
    height: 40px;
}
```

HTML

```
<button id="button">Click me</button>
```

JS

```
var btn = document.getElementById("button");

btn.addEventListener("mouseover", handler);


function handler(scope){
     scope.target.className = "buttonWithImage";
     console.log(scope.target);
}
```

Comment: I got an error saying "unable to get property 'addEventListener' of undefined or null reference"

Comment: @jenna make sure your JS is at the 'bottom' of the HTML code (not at the top) - this way it will execute after the HTML is loaded and it will find the elements necessary